# Can you ignore specific redundant qualifiers in Resharper?

Tags: vb.net, resharper

We have always used Me.Property and Me.Control in our VB projects, and have just got ReSharper. Does anyone know of a way to get it to ignore this specific type if redundant qualifier?

I still want it to complain if I use any other redundant qualifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the setting which actually stops the warning from appearing.

```
Options > Code Inspection > Inspection Severity > VB.NET > Redundancies in Code
```

Find Redundant 'Me.' Qualifier and change it from "Warning" to "Do Not Show".

[image: Redundant 'Me' Qualifier]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, all known cases of qualifier redundancy are currently covered by this single inspection, which means that you can't tell ReSharper to ignore occurrences of `Me` but still highlight, say, explicit namespace references.

Here's a relevant [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-288096) that you're free to vote for and watch.

Comment: That feature request claims it is fixed, but I couldn't actually find how to do it in Resharper 9.1.1